# change GroupControl visibility of opened usercontrol from the form vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have one 'UserControl' that opened inside form,
this usercontrol has a 'GroupControl'
how can I make this 'GroupControl' hidden or visible when user click on a button that beings on the form
using vb.net

Comment: Add a `GroupControlVisible` property to the `UserControl` and have it get and set the `Visible` property of the child control.

Comment: can you explain more

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To Simplify, you can use :

```
MyParentForm.UserControlName1.GroupControlName.Visible = False
```

or

```
CType(MyParentForm.Controls("UserControlName").Controls("GroupControlName"), _
                GroupControl).Visible = False
```

But the best way is create a property which allows changing the Visible property of the `GroupControl` in `UserControl` Class like this :

```
Public Property GroupControlVisibility() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.GroupControlName.Visible
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Me.GroupControlName.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Not working, I'm facing this error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: MyUserControl.GroupControlVisible = True

Comment: what do you mean by "GroupControlName", and whats is the GroupControl

Comment: GroupControlName is the name of GroupControl; and GroupControl is Type for casting.

Comment: Ok, Perfect, Solved. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

In you UserControl add a procedure how set visibility to your GroupControl :

```
 Public sub SetVisibility (V as boolean)
     YourGroupControl.visible=v
 End Sub
```

In your form

```
   Public Class Form1
        Dim uc As New MyUserControl
        Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Me.Controls.Add(uc)
            uc.Dock()

        End Sub

        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            uc.SetVisibility(False)

            'NB :MyUserControl is name of your usercontrol

        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: Possible, but bad practice. Child controls shouldn't be exposed publicly.

Comment: you are right ,i have edit my answer to lift this vulnerability

Comment: I checked the both solutions without luck, for more explain, the child is usercontrol that beings inside the parent form

Comment: @Jassimi if you put your code for check what you are traying .

Comment: I'm trying to make groupcontrol visible, this groupcontrol on the usercontrol, and the usercontrol will load inside panelcontrol that beings on the main form

Comment: If you follow my solution step by step you can acomplish that ,else you can past just the code where you call and and add your userControl in form

Answer (score 1):

In the user control:

```
Public Property GroupControlVisible() As Boolean
    Get
        Return Me.GroupControl1.Visible
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        Me.GroupControl1.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```